# ionic can't run platform windows

Tags: cordova, ionic2, windows

D:\mobile\newionictwo>cordova run windows -- --phone
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" D:\mobile\newionictwo\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js D:\mobile\newionictwo
add to body class: platform-windows
Building project: D:\mobile\newionictwo\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj
        Configuration : debug
        Platform      : anycpu
  CordovaApp.Windows10 -> D:\mobile\newionictwo\platforms\windows\AppPackages\CordovaApp.Windows10_0.0.1.0_anycpu_debug_Test\CordovaApp.Windows10_0.0.1.0_an
  ycpu_debug.appx
Deploying windows10 package to device:
D:\mobile\newionictwo\platforms\windows\AppPackages\CordovaApp.Windows10_0.0.1.0_anycpu_debug_Test\CordovaApp.Windows10_0.0.1.0_anycpu_debug.appx
Attempting to remove previously installed application...
**Error: Cannot read property '__ip' of undefined**

Answer (score 1):

First install windows Os
Then follow below steps
You need to add Cordova Inappbrowser in order to use it.

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

or

```
window.open('http://apache.org','_system','location=no');
```

Make sure to check deviceready state or (for ionic) $ionicPlatform.ready before using it.

https://www.badpenguin.org/how-to-make-your-ionic-cordova-app-to-run-under-windows-phone-8-1-and-desktop

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/developer-resources/platform-setup/windows-setup.html

Answer (score -1):

If this command returns no results

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\WinAppDeployCmd.exe" devices
```

Then you need to start your IP over USB Service

```
net start IpOverUsbSvc
```